# Estimate of rounding error and optimal step size in GSL deriv

Tags: algorithm, precision, numerical-methods, gsl

I am trying to implement at curvature estimation routine (in octave, but that is not essential). That is, a routine that calculates the 2nd derivative of a given function in a given point.

I base my routine on the [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) routine `gsl_deriv_central`, which calculate the derivative of a given function in a given point, together with the 4th order finite difference formula for the 2nd derivative.

- The source for the `gsl_deriv_central` routine can be found in the tar archive of the latest GSL (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-latest.tar.gz) under the folder "deriv" in the file "deriv.c".
  "deriv.c" is for reference also included in the end of this post.
- Wikipedia have a list of finite difference coefficients (Finite_difference_coefficient) and an article about the 4th order method called Five-point stencil (Five-point_stencil).

The GSL routine basically estimate the derivative of a function using the approximation that
f '(x) = ( f(x-2h) - 8 f(x-h) + 8 f(x+h) - f(x+2h) ) / (12h) + O(h^4)
and I can then in a similar fashion approximate the second derivative as
f ''(x) = ( -f(x-2h) + 16 f(x-h) - 30 f(x) + 16 f(x+h) - f(x+2h) ) / (12 h^2) + O(h^4)

These approximation are obliviously only good as long as stepsize, h, is chosen wisely. The GSL routine first performs a trial calculation of the derivative and then from the errors in this calculation estimates an optimal h and redo the calculation using that optimal h.
My problem now is that I do not fully understand this part of the `gsl_deriv_central` routine and therefore can not construct a similar method to estimate an optimal h for my curvature routine. I hope someone can fill out the gaps in my understanding.

### `gsl_deriv_central` in my understanding

In order to find this optimal stepsize `h_opt` the `gsl_deriv_central` routine needs to estimate the absolute rounding error `round` and the absolute truncation error `trunc`. It does so in the subroutine `central_deriv` (not important unless you're looking at the source).

The truncation error is estimated rather roughly as the difference between the result using the 4th order method and the result one obtain from the 2nd order method:
f '(x) = (f(x+h) - f(x-h))/(2h) + O(h^2)
This I understand and this can be implemented analogously for the curvature routine.

The rounding error is more troublesome though. First, in my understanding, the rounding error of the finite difference is estimated. That is the rounding error of:
f(x-2h) - 8 f(x-h) + 8 f(x+h) - f(x+2h)
In `deriv_central` the rounding error on the finite difference is called `e5` and it is calculated as

```
double e5 = 2.0 * (fabs (fph) + fabs (fmh)) * GSL_DBL_EPSILON + (fabs (fp1) + fabs (fm1)) * GSL_DBL_EPSILON;
```

where `fph`, `fmh`, `fp1` and `fm1` are "f(x+h)", "f(x-h)", "f(x+2h)" and "f(x-2h)", respectively, and `GSL_DBL_EPSILON` is the machine accuracy (2.2204e-16).
*I guess* the reason for this is that for addition and subtraction the rounding error obtained is proportional to the order of the largest number in the calculation times the machine accuracy. Summing all the absolute values is then a way to estimate the order of the error. (I haven't been able to find a source confirming this guess and I am in doubt whether it is because it is obvious or because it is wrong...)
`deriv_central` determines another contribution to the rounding error originating from the arguments to the function. That is, because there's a rounding error when the small stepsize h is added or subtracted from x, this will propagate to an error on the derivative. This error is called `dy` and calculated as

```
double dy = GSL_MAX (fabs (r3 / h), fabs (r5 / h)) *(fabs (x) / h) * GSL_DBL_EPSILON;
```

where

```
double r3 = 0.5 * (fp1 - fm1);
double r5 = (4.0 / 3.0) * (fph - fmh) - (1.0 / 3.0) * r3;
```

is the 2nd order finite difference and the 4th order finite difference, respectively. Why `dy` is calculated this way I cannot see. The last factor `(fabs (x) / h) * GSL_DBL_EPSILON` is the relative error in the argument (x ± h). I tried to make sense of `dy` from the law of propagation of uncertainty (ref: wikipedia article: Propagation_of_uncertainty#Simplification), but failed.
Anyway the total rounding error is then:

```
double round = fabs (e5 / h) + dy;
```

*I guess* the division by `h` here is since the rounding error is on the derivative (and not just the finite difference). Therefore when I calculate the curvature the rounding error of the corresponding finite difference *I guess* it should be divided by h^2.

With estimates for `trunc` and `round` `gsl_deriv_central` goes on to calculate `h_opt` as

```
double h_opt = h * pow (round / (2.0 * trunc), 1.0 / 3.0);
```

This formula I have so far not been able to find a reference for, but as is also written in the comments in the source the rounding error scales with 1/h and the truncation scales with h^2 (because it is estimated from the 2th order approximation to the derivative). If we write that as

1. trunc = eT*h^2 + O(h^3)
2. round = eR*1/h + O(1)

where eT and eR are coefficients of the significant terms, then the total error would be

3. error = trunc + round ~ eT*h^2 + eR*1/h

this is minimised by

4. error'(h = h_opt) = 0
5. ⇒ 2 h_opt*eT - 1/h_opt^2 * eR = 0
6. ⇒ h_opt = (eR/(2 eT))^(1/3) ≈ ((round*h)/(2 trunc/h^2))^(1/3) = h (round/(2 trunc))^(1/3)

where 1) and 2) have been used again in 7) to obtain the expression of `h_opt`.
Does anyone see serious problems in this argument?
If not, I would be able to apply the same arguments to calculate an optimal stepsize for the curvature routine. In that case the truncation error would still scale as h^2, but the rounding error *would maybe* scale as 1/h^2, depending on how `dy` should be understood and whether the corresponding `e5` should be divided by h^2 in the calculation of the rounding error.

Finally, trying to make sense of `gsl_deriv_central`, I at some point resorted to "Numerical recipes in C++" (2nd edition) (just a C++ version of Numerical recipes in C, which some people seem to think a bible). This book suggest to avoid the problem with adding and subtracting h to x by defining new h's as

```
temp = x + h
h_new = temp - x
```

the arguments to the function would then be representable as floating point numbers.
Can anyone judge whether this would be a way to circumvent the need of calculating `dy`?

If anyone read this far, thanks! I hope you can give my at least some hints to understanding these estimates of rounding errors.
Also I am sorry for the misuse of formatting in this post, missing links and ugly math, but my formatting and posting permissions are quite restricted, since this is my first post.

### Summary of questions

1. How is the rounding error of a sum/difference estimated?
2. Why is `dy` calculated as it is in `deriv_central`?
3. Why is the rounding error of the finite difference `e5` divided by `h` when calculating the rounding error of the derivative?

   - When estimating the rounding error for a corresponding curvature calculation, should I divide by h^2 instead?
4. Are there serious problems with my arguments for the `h_opt` formula?
5. Could I avoid calculating a `dy` just by working with a `h_new` as suggested by "Numerical recipes in C++"?

### Appendix: `deriv.c`

For the reference I here include `deriv.c` from the source for GSL:

```
/* deriv/deriv.c
 * 
 * Copyright (C) 2004, 2007 Brian Gough
 * 
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or (at
 * your option) any later version.
 * 
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
 * WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
 */

#include <config.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_deriv.h>

static void
central_deriv (const gsl_function * f, double x, double h,
               double *result, double *abserr_round, double *abserr_trunc)
{
  /* Compute the derivative using the 5-point rule (x-h, x-h/2, x,
     x+h/2, x+h). Note that the central point is not used.  

     Compute the error using the difference between the 5-point and
     the 3-point rule (x-h,x,x+h). Again the central point is not
     used. */

  double fm1 = GSL_FN_EVAL (f, x - h);
  double fp1 = GSL_FN_EVAL (f, x + h);

  double fmh = GSL_FN_EVAL (f, x - h / 2);
  double fph = GSL_FN_EVAL (f, x + h / 2);

  double r3 = 0.5 * (fp1 - fm1);
  double r5 = (4.0 / 3.0) * (fph - fmh) - (1.0 / 3.0) * r3;

  double e3 = (fabs (fp1) + fabs (fm1)) * GSL_DBL_EPSILON;
  double e5 = 2.0 * (fabs (fph) + fabs (fmh)) * GSL_DBL_EPSILON + e3;

  /* The next term is due to finite precision in x+h = O (eps * x) */

  double dy = GSL_MAX (fabs (r3 / h), fabs (r5 / h)) *(fabs (x) / h) * GSL_DBL_EPSILON;

  /* The truncation error in the r5 approximation itself is O(h^4).
     However, for safety, we estimate the error from r5-r3, which is
     O(h^2).  By scaling h we will minimise this estimated error, not
     the actual truncation error in r5. */

  *result = r5 / h;
  *abserr_trunc = fabs ((r5 - r3) / h); /* Estimated truncation error O(h^2) */
  *abserr_round = fabs (e5 / h) + dy;   /* Rounding error (cancellations) */
}

int
gsl_deriv_central (const gsl_function * f, double x, double h,
                   double *result, double *abserr)
{
  double r_0, round, trunc, error;
  central_deriv (f, x, h, &r_0, &round, &trunc);
  error = round + trunc;

  if (round < trunc && (round > 0 && trunc > 0))
    {
      double r_opt, round_opt, trunc_opt, error_opt;

      /* Compute an optimised stepsize to minimize the total error,
         using the scaling of the truncation error (O(h^2)) and
         rounding error (O(1/h)). */

      double h_opt = h * pow (round / (2.0 * trunc), 1.0 / 3.0);
      central_deriv (f, x, h_opt, &r_opt, &round_opt, &trunc_opt);
      error_opt = round_opt + trunc_opt;

      /* Check that the new error is smaller, and that the new derivative 
         is consistent with the error bounds of the original estimate. */

      if (error_opt < error && fabs (r_opt - r_0) < 4.0 * error)
        {
          r_0 = r_opt;
          error = error_opt;
        }
    }

  *result = r_0;
  *abserr = error;

  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}


static void
forward_deriv (const gsl_function * f, double x, double h,
               double *result, double *abserr_round, double *abserr_trunc)
{
  /* Compute the derivative using the 4-point rule (x+h/4, x+h/2,
     x+3h/4, x+h).

     Compute the error using the difference between the 4-point and
     the 2-point rule (x+h/2,x+h).  */

  double f1 = GSL_FN_EVAL (f, x + h / 4.0);
  double f2 = GSL_FN_EVAL (f, x + h / 2.0);
  double f3 = GSL_FN_EVAL (f, x + (3.0 / 4.0) * h);
  double f4 = GSL_FN_EVAL (f, x + h);

  double r2 = 2.0*(f4 - f2);
  double r4 = (22.0 / 3.0) * (f4 - f3) - (62.0 / 3.0) * (f3 - f2) +
    (52.0 / 3.0) * (f2 - f1);

  /* Estimate the rounding error for r4 */

  double e4 = 2 * 20.67 * (fabs (f4) + fabs (f3) + fabs (f2) + fabs (f1)) * GSL_DBL_EPSILON;

  /* The next term is due to finite precision in x+h = O (eps * x) */

  double dy = GSL_MAX (fabs (r2 / h), fabs (r4 / h)) * fabs (x / h) * GSL_DBL_EPSILON;

  /* The truncation error in the r4 approximation itself is O(h^3).
     However, for safety, we estimate the error from r4-r2, which is
     O(h).  By scaling h we will minimise this estimated error, not
     the actual truncation error in r4. */

  *result = r4 / h;
  *abserr_trunc = fabs ((r4 - r2) / h); /* Estimated truncation error O(h) */
  *abserr_round = fabs (e4 / h) + dy;
}

int
gsl_deriv_forward (const gsl_function * f, double x, double h,
                   double *result, double *abserr)
{
  double r_0, round, trunc, error;
  forward_deriv (f, x, h, &r_0, &round, &trunc);
  error = round + trunc;

  if (round < trunc && (round > 0 && trunc > 0))
    {
      double r_opt, round_opt, trunc_opt, error_opt;

      /* Compute an optimised stepsize to minimize the total error,
         using the scaling of the estimated truncation error (O(h)) and
         rounding error (O(1/h)). */

      double h_opt = h * pow (round / (trunc), 1.0 / 2.0);
      forward_deriv (f, x, h_opt, &r_opt, &round_opt, &trunc_opt);
      error_opt = round_opt + trunc_opt;

      /* Check that the new error is smaller, and that the new derivative 
         is consistent with the error bounds of the original estimate. */

      if (error_opt < error && fabs (r_opt - r_0) < 4.0 * error)
        {
          r_0 = r_opt;
          error = error_opt;
        }
    }

  *result = r_0;
  *abserr = error;

  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

int
gsl_deriv_backward (const gsl_function * f, double x, double h,
                    double *result, double *abserr)
{
  return gsl_deriv_forward (f, x, -h, result, abserr);
}
```

You can find a copy of the GNU General Public License, under which the above file is available, at gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.htm